# Is there a means to name a slide - and select the slide by this name as opposed to the slide index?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Similarly to how objects on a slide can be named, and called upon & selected by that name, I would like to shift between, move to & select slides using a designated name.

So where I would currently employ, for instance:

```
PPPres.Slides(1).Select
```

I need to do something along the lines of:

```
PPPres.Slides("Slide Name").Select
```

- mainly because the slides are potentially dynamic, and I'm not keen on changing references for every slide within each block of code every time the slide changes.

Honestly can't find any features for actually naming a slide within Powerpoint. I have read features about doing this by naming the Title Object, but this doesn't seem to make sense to me, nor does it actually work for me.

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint names its slides in **order**, so the first slide is named `"Slide1"`, the second `"Slide2"`, etc...

You can use the **default** name or you can **manually** change it, like in this example:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide2").Name = "Hello" 'Changing the default name to "Hello"
ActivePresentation.Slides("Hello").Select 'Using the new Name to access the Slide
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - not entirely sure this is what I'm looking for though.
Imagine running the code and, which inputs data into Slide 3 - then moving Slide 3 into position 1, rerunning the code, and the correct updated data moving onto the slide now in Position 1 (hope that makes sense).

Suppose what I'm asking is, is the Slide hardcoded with the name "Slide3" no matter its position in the file, or does its name depend on the position it is dynamically placed?

Comment: @ThomasGardner The slide name is hardcoded when it's created. From that moment on, you can change its position, but the name will still remain the same (unless you manually change it), so you can be sure that changing the position will not affect your code.

Comment: That's great thanks - how would I determine the name of the slide? (i.e. "Slide3", which might be at Index 1)

Comment: (and final point, I suppose alluding to my original question) - is there at all a way to change the name of "Slide3" etc to a custom title, i.e. "Monthly Data"?

Comment: I think the quickest solution would be to exceute this code  `ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide3").Select` and see what slides is selected. (Change "Slide3" with the slide you're insterestd in).

Comment: To change the slide name, you can see my answer: it changes the name from "Slide2" to "Hello"

Comment: @ThomasGardner If you found this answer helpful, consider accepting it, so others can benefit from it :)